# How to truncate main URL alone in Qt string

Tags: string, qt, split

I've a Qstring with an URL content like the below.

https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qstring.html#split

I would like to know the simplest way to parse the main URL from the above URL. I want my output as below.

https://het.as.utexas.edu

Similar way, if there is a html URL with several parameters attached to it, I want the ".html" part alone.

Comment: as @Thomenson answered, you should look into QUrl documentation, you can get most of that stuff by a query from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QUrl`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl

You can get the root by `host` method and used protocol by `scheme` method. Quick example:

```cpp
QUrl url("https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qstring.html#split");
auto host = url.scheme() + "://" + url.host();
```

Comment: I would check if scheme is empty by first querying with `isRelative()`, and if it is, omit the `"://"`